# Fingerprint in PuTTY host key warning does not match EC2 key fingerprint

Tags: ssh, putty, public-key

I rebooted my AWS EC2 instance, and now when I try to connect via SSH or FTP, I get the PuTTY warning about a potential security breach and that the host key doesn't match the one cached in the registry. The IP for the EC2 instance is still the same, and I looked at my key pair fingerprint in AWS EC2 dashboard (if you click on the key pair assigned to the instance, it will show you a fingerprint) and it doesn't match the one that is shown in the warning message from PuTTY. Additionally, the site hosted on the instance is not available, I get a connection refused error.

I fully stopped and restarted the EC2 instance and it is now showing a different IP address, so I associated a new elastic IP.

Now when I connect I get the normal message I've pretty much always ignored in the past when I first connect to a new instance, but now I'm super paranoid to accept the host key.

The fingerprint displayed by PuTTY shows that it's a ssh-ed25519 fingerprint. But when I look at the fingerprint in AWS it's an RSA fingerprint. They don't match, but I don't imagine they would since they're different types. What steps should I take to ensure I'm not screwing myself?

I went to the PuTTY host key setting and moved RSA to the top of the list, which I think is a step in the right direction because now PuTTY  prompts with RSA2, but the fingerprints still don't match, presumably because it's RSA2 and AWS shows RSA. I don't know which option to move to the top.

I also tried to manually configure the host keys by pasting the fingerprint I want it to accept (pulled from AWS), but it says the host key is not in the right format. I guess that despite it saying you can specify a fingerprint, it must not allow a fingerprint and wants a host key.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at your account's authentication key fingerprint.

That's not what PuTTY prompts you for. PuTTY prompts you for the server's key (aka hostkey).

Use EC2 console to open web-based terminal to your server and use `ssh-keygen` to display the hostkey fingerprints. For example:

```
sudo ssh-keygen -l -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

For details, see my guide for [Connecting securely to Amazon EC2 server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_ec2)